# Error in Delphi with perlregex in file

Tags: delphi

I have a problem with perlregex, the issue is not whether such use is in the component perlregex txt file but I want to open the file has characters that do not understand and I know how hard I have to use it to search in perl perlregex, went up a link to the file: http://uploaded.net/file/ghhm0xv4, I'm sure the problem is in the text file because I use the component perlregex well, if they want to see the code on how to use the perlregex component you can see here.

```
unit test;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, PerlRegEx;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    PerlRegEx1: TPerlRegEx;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function ReverseString(const S: string): string;
var
  i, len: Integer;
begin
  len := Length(S);
  SetLength(Result, len);
  for i := len downto 1 do
  begin
    Result[len - i + 1] := S[i];
  end;
end;


procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  conte: TMemoryStream;
  source: string;

begin

  conte := TMemoryStream.Create;
  conte.LoadFromFile('test.txt');
  SetString(source, PAnsiChar(conte.Memory), conte.Size);

  source := ReverseString(source);

  PerlRegEx1.Regex := '} 2 E R E H { (.*) } 2 E R E H {';
  PerlRegEx1.Subject := source;

  if PerlRegEx1.Match then
  begin
    Edit1.Text := PerlRegEx1.SubExpressions[1];
  end;

  end;

end.
```

the problem is that it does not find anything, the program does not throw any errors in general, I suspect the problem is in the text file, not if I have to do something to the file content to use perlregex

Comment: Have you used Google translate? What are you asking here? Voted to close, until you correct the question.

Comment: yes , my English is bad

Comment: Try to correct the question. Also, that code can not compile. That syntax is invalid.

Comment: @Matias: Please stop deleting the content of your question. It has received an answer, and removing the content makes that answer meaningless. If you keep deleting the content, I'm going to flag your actions for the moderators to intervene. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example (with test text) that matches your RegEx perfectly. If it doesn't work for you with your text file, you need to examine the actual content of your text file (with a hex editor, for instance) to see what it actually contains.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, PerlRegex;

var
  RegEx: TPerlRegex;
  i: Integer;

begin
  RegEx := TPerlRegEx.Create;

  try
    { TODO -oUser -cConsole Main : Insert code here }
    RegEx.Subject := 'some test text before } 2 E R E H { This is found text } 2 E R E Htext after';
    RegEx.RegEx := '} 2 E R E H { (.*) } 2 E R E H';
    if RegEx.Match then
      WriteLn(RegEx.Groups[1])
    else
      WriteLn('No match found');
    ReadLn;
  finally
    RegEx.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Here's the output of running the test application:

[image: Samle regex match from test app]